# Query a field in an embedded document in MongoDb that throws "The left-hand side of the Call operator must be a direct access to a persisted property"

Tags: .net, mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas, realm-mobile-platform

I have an **embedded** document in Atlas, where I am trying to query a field (i.e. document.ProfileTab.AadharNo) from **Realm**, but getting
Exception: **System.NotSupportedException: 'The left-hand side of the Call operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm**.
Unable to process 'c.ProfileTab.AadharNo'.'

From Realm sdk, I am trying to query the field like this:

```
var v = App.realmInstance.All<App.ArogyaMainClass>().Where(
    c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ProfileTab.AadharNo) 
    && 
    c.ProfileTab.AadharNo.Equals(entryAadharNo.Text.Trim())
    )
    .ToList();
```

Is creating an index on the field will help? If Realm is expecting persisted field, what it is and how to make the field persisted? Do I need to set [required] on the field? Plz suggest some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Below are the Realm Object Models:

```
        public class ArogyaMainClass : RealmObject
    {
        [MapTo("_id")]
        [PrimaryKey]
        public ObjectId? Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
        [MapTo("profileTab")]
        public ArogyaProfileTab ProfileTab { get; set; }
    }


        public class ArogyaProfileTab : EmbeddedObject
    {
        [MapTo("PatientName")]
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        [MapTo("AadharNo")]
        public string AadharNo { get; set; }
        [MapTo("PhoneNo")]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I am not really clear on what this `c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ProfileTab.AadharNo)` resolved to. What is `c` and does it  have a ProfileTab.AadharNo set of peristed properties? Can you include your Realm object model?

Comment: Hi Jay, this is lambda expression used in linq query. 'c' is just an iterator just like we take 'i' in for loop. c.ProfileTab.AadharNo will resolve to checking each document for the embedded field AadharNo in each document. I forgot to include the Realm object model. I am including it now in the question.

Comment: Part of the question issue is the naming conventions. Typically, in programming vars and properties are *lower* cased; *Capital* letters are reserved for Class, Struct and Enum names. The question has a mix so the code is hard to decipher; lower cased `MapTo("profileTab")` but then upper cased here `MapTo("PatientName")`. Then the public vars are Uppercased but the backing vars are Upper/lower which may cause a typo issue. Generally, the compiler doesn't care but it makes the code unclear. What's the coding platform? What's persisted? Is this `entryAadharNo` nil? Please include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the LINQ implementation of the .NET Realm SDK does not yet support querying on linked objects.
In order to achieve what you showed, you need to use [Filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/dotnet/latest/reference/Realms.CollectionExtensions.html#Realms_CollectionExtensions_Filter__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_String_Realms_RealmValue___). The language used in the filter method is called [Realm Query Language](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/realm-query-language/).

The query for your need would look like

```cs
var v = App.realmInstance.All<App.ArogyaMainClass>().Filter("ProfileTab.AadharNo.@count > 0 AND ProfileTab.AadharNo == $0", entryAadharNo.Text.Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: Will this work if I have 3 to 4 levels of nesting? And can indexing that field be helpful in the search?

Comment: Yes it will work with nesting > 2. Indexes speed up some queries at the cost of slightly slower write times and additional storage and memory overhead. So the worthiness heavily depends on the use case. If this is a query that's run many times, it could be worth running some internal testing with and without indexing that field.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the support. I will get in touch if I need to know anything further.